# disappeared my getstream.io app. Can I find this?

Tags: getstream-io

It happened today.
We have an app called "ticketsolution" but we can no longer find it in the dashboard.
When viewing with app keys and secret keys, the existing data is as good as it was before the app was gone.
Is there a way to recover that app?
Please let me know that the issue has been resolved.

Comment: https://getstream.io/submit-bug-report/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bug report